# how to change output html of variable $output on file views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php

Tags: views

dpm($output) -> `<a href="/content/photo-08"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://www.flipbook.dev/sites/default/files/styles/337x220/public/document_images/9.jpg" width="337" height="220" alt="" /></a>` on file  views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php so how to I can add `<div class="amezing"></div> => <a href=""><img /><div class="amezing"></div></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kind of answered yourself already.

open the views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php file, look for that  and add what you need.

however, use the file you can find inside your theme folder ( usually named templates or tpl), not inside the view module.

if you can't find it in there, copy it from the view module. In this case clear the cache for drupal to register the new file.

Always and only edit the .tpl of your themes.

Comment: Thanks for support but i tryed. Content of views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php =>  <?php print $output;?> i'll try 
<?php print $output.'<div class="myclass"></div>';?>  but results  <a><img /></a><div class="myclass"></div>  =>> i want <a><div class="myclass"></div></a>

Comment: Oh, i didn't get it. In this case, well, you need to work on a preprocess function, or just a simple hack. The first, i have no idea. The second, add a $output=strreplace('</a>', 'your divs</a>', $output); before the print command.

Comment: That good idea, it's worked  
Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Instated of  `<?php print $output;?>` in `views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php` file.

just print

```
<?php print_r($view->result);?>
```

You can able to edit the fields as you want.